# SASS interpolation error

Tags: css, sass, shopify, templating

I'm in the processing of converting my Shopify theme's CSS into SASS. I'm using the SASS interpolation tags `#{}` to handle the embedded shopify template code in my CSS.

I'm running into one error though that's stumping me. The SCSS is as follows...

`background-image: #{'{% if settings.use-background-image %}'} url( #{ '{{ "background-image.png" | asset_url }}' } ) #{'{% endif %}'};`

and my error is...

`error style.scss (Line 83: Invalid CSS after "...{'{% endif %}'}": expected string, was ";")`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The Sass parser simply can't figure out what you're trying to do (neither can I, honestly).  Trying to mix Sass with your template code like that is a bad idea in general.  If you're interested in how to approach your problem the Sass way, update your question with what you are trying to do and someone might be able to help you out.

Comment: @cimmanon — "Trying to mix Sass with your template code like that is a bad idea in general" — Not sure I'd agree with that statement. I don't think I'd want to forgo the preprocessor entirely just because I'm working on a project with a template language.


The code above is simply a test example where the desired output is `background-image: {% if settings.use-background-image %} url({{ "background-image.png" | asset_url }}) {% endif %};`

This one example alone throws an error and I'm unable to determine what specifically the parser can't figure out.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
.test {
    $test: '{% if settings.use-background-image %} url({{ "background-image.png" | asset_url }}) {% endif %}';
    background-image: unquote($test);
}
```

Generates this:

```
.test {
  background-image: {% if settings.use-background-image %} url({{ "background-image.png" | asset_url }}) {% endif %};
}
```